# How to show hidden text using .animate()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to know, how to show hidden text using .animate(), when I don't know height of the paragraph? Solution mustuse .animate() because of context.

```
$(".moreText").click(function() {
    $(".paragraph").animate({height: "???px"});
    return false;
});

$(".lessText").click(function() {
    $(".paragraph").animate({height:"60px"});
    return false;
});
```

I dont know height of paragraph because it's hidden. At the beginning, it has active class .lessText.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `slideToggle` (see [documentation here](https://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/)) ?

If you really want to use `animate`, you don't have to know the actual height, you can use this :

```
animate({height: 'toggle'});
```

as described [here in the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#animation-properties), but if your element is actually hidden (`display: none` for example), you will have to show it manually.

> Note: Unlike shorthand animation methods such as .slideDown() and
>   .fadeIn(), the .animate() method does not make hidden elements visible
>   as part of the effect. For example, given $( "someElement"
>   ).hide().animate({height: "20px"}, 500), the animation will run, but
>   the element will remain hidden.

Comment: I tried your advice but it has opposite effect. animate({height: 'toggle'}); hide everything instead of show more. It is down on index of webpage www.checkitout.over.cz in section: "NOVINKY". When I set height of paragraph more than 60px, it will show more...

Comment: @user3294950 Just some design advice: slow down the transition between the sandwiches. That's way too fast (or maybe something's gone wrong).

Comment: @user3294950 Also, this "show text" thing seems rather pointless. Instead of trying to fix this problem, you should just write shorter + more succinct descriptions or just let it flow around the side of the picture by default. You're just possibly making the user click more things, which is no bueno

Answer (score 0):

You could use the jQuery method `.height()` to get the height of the paragraph. Then you could assign it to a variable that your function using `.animate()` has access to. Something like this: `var pHeight = $('.paragraph').height();`, then just pass in `pHeight` for your value later.